# unique_together not working as expected in view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I added unique_together in the Django model. It works fine in the Django admin panel but doesn't work when I create model instances in a for loop in the Django view.

**My Model:**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    attribute_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attribute_2 = models.IntegerField()
    attribute_3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("attribute_1", "attribute_2"),)
```

**View:**

```
class ParentView(View):
    template_name = "app/index.html"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        for i in range(10):
            Parent.objects.create(
                attribute_1=f"value-{i}",
                attribute_2=i,
                attribute_3=f"value-{i}",
            )
        return render(self.request, self.template_name)
```

**Problem:**

When I open this view, it creates the entries in the Parent model. when I refresh the page, I expect a unique value error but it doesn't give any error at all and creates entries again. No matter how much time I reload the page, it creates duplicate entries without giving an error.

**What I tried?**

1. I tried to change my DB from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL but it didn't work.
2. I tried to switch attributes but no luck.
3. It works perfectly fine on the admin panel.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Django version 4.0.8 with python version 3.10.6 if someone is interested to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works perfectly fine on the admin panel.

That is because it is validated by a `ModelForm`, you can check this before saving with [**`.full_clean(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean):

```
class ParentView(View):
    template_name = 'app/index.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(10):
            parent = Parent(
                attribute_1=f'value-{i}',
                attribute_2=i,
                attribute_3=f'value-{i}',
            )
            parent.full_clean()
            parent.save()
        return render(self.request, self.template_name)
```

Most databases *can* enforce unique constraints, you will have to `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).

Comment: that's extremely helpful, thank you so much for your comment.
can you please further explain to me how to get rid of the database call that the full_clean() method makes? Since I'm in for loop and if it's a big loop then it's gonna make a problem for me. I've tried bulk_create and bulk_update, but none of them verifies the duplicates.

Comment: @SaadatAli: make migrations and migrate the database. Likely you will first need to remove the duplicates before the `migrate` can add the constraint to the db.